# Is it possible to call actions only on mouseup ( mouserelease) in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseup

I have a `NSButton` and an `action` associated with `Button`. I would like to invoke the `action` method only on mouseup (mouserelease).Is it possible? If it is possible how to do that?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094763/simple-mouseover-effect-on-nsbutton). May help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A click is a mouseDown followed by a mouseUp, so a normal action method is not called until the mouseUp anyway, so I don't know what other behavior you would want.

Comment: you can find my answer here... instead of changing the background image call your method... it may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094763/simple-mouseover-effect-on-nsbutton/22023238#22023238